# Quarkus : Wait for business init logic to run before starting Integration Test

Tags: quarkus

I have an application whose init requires some business logic to run. This has been implemented via implementing a `io.quarkus.runtime.QuarkusApplication` whose `run()` method initialises the application.

My problem is that when writing a `@QuarkusIntegrationTest` I have a `@BeforeAll` method which does the test data setup and this test data setup needs to be executed after the init logic in the `io.quarkus.runtime.QuarkusApplication` has completed.

Is there any way to enforce this ?

Comment: Could you implement a readiness check in the application, and then check/wait on the readiness endpoint in your test? https://redhat-developer-demos.github.io/quarkus-tutorial/quarkus-tutorial/health.html walks through adding a custom readiness endpoint.

Comment: A readiness check that depends on the callers discretion doesn't work. It could solve my current integration test but from a future maintainability point of view it would be a nightmare as the dependency is very fragile and obscure.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly I think you can solve your issue with the `@QuarkusTestResource` annotation. I use this with `@QuarkusTest` tests, but I think it should work with the `@QuarkusIntegrationTest` as well

Implement the `QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager` interface in the class where you have your prerequisite business logic (e.g. `TestResource.class`) and then annotate your test class with `@QuarkusTestResource(value = TestResource.class)`.

This will initialize your test resource before the Quarkus runtime starts. You could then also inject the test resource into your test class for interaction with the more here:
https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#quarkus-test-resource

Comment: That's a good idea but it won't work in my case. The business init logic depends on another QuarkusTestResource namely the Postgres container and there is no way in Quarkus to establish a dependency between two QuarkusTestResources

Comment: I see, you have a bit more complex situation there. 
Well, potentially you could inject both of the QuarkusTestResources into your test class (there is an example in the docs linked above) and then through the test class control both of the resources, could that work for you?